# Change the class of and object. (Other aproachs?)

Tags: java, c++, class, inheritance, runtime

I have had several situations when i would like to do that. This could be an example:

Consider a possible implementation for the chess game. We define the abstract class 'Piece' and classes inheriting from it: 'bishop' 'peon' 'tower' 'horse' 'queen' etc

We may have our peon about to reach the end of the board, and it may be required for a method called onto that peon object to change the class of that object to 'Queen', 'horse' or whatever.

So my question is, is there any way to do that in C++ or Java? If not, in any other language?
Also, are there other approaches for this situations in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) or the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

With decorator:

```
interface ChessPiece {
    Set<Move> getPossibleMoves();
    Image getAppearance();
}

class Pawn implements ChessPiece {
    ...
}

class Decorator implements ChessPiece {
    ChessPiece decorated;

    public Decorator(ChessPiece decorated_) {
        this.decorated = decorated_;
    }

    @override
    Set<Move> getPossibleMoves() {
        Set<Move> result = decorated.getPossibleMoves();
        // alter result
        return result;
    }
}
```

When needed you replace the `Pawn` instance with the `Decorated` instance.  *So it still involves replacing one instance with an other as mentioned in [OpenSause's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/583274/opensauce) answer.*

```
ChessPiece pawn = new Pawn;
...
pawn = new Decorated(pawn);
```

When you plan ahead you can use strategy *it is still not really changing classes*:

```
interface PossibleMovesStrategy {
    Set<Move> getPossibleMoves();
}

interface AppearanceStrategy {
    Image getAppearance();
}

class ChangingChessPiece extends ChessPiece {
    PossibleMovesStrategy posMoves;
    AppearanceStrategy appearance;

    @override
    Set<Move> getPossibleMoves() {
        return posMoves.getPossibleMoves();
    }

    @override
    Image getAppearance() {
        return appearance.getAppearance();
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit of explanation of how the decorator pattern might apply would be useful.  I don't see it personally.

Answer (score 10):

In languages like C++ or Java I'd then create a new instance of 'Queen' or 'Horse' and replace the 'Peon' instance with that new one.

Comment: +1 Just as you do when you are playing chess. You don't change the shape of the peon, you swap the pieces.

Comment: This is actually incorrect.  You're not "replacing" the `Peon` instance.  That instance is going to be orphaned as the pointer that used to point to it is now pointing to a new instance of `Queen`.  The `Peon` instance is going to be garbage collected at some later time.

Comment: @Milimetric well, replacing from your application logic's point of view. From a memory allocation point of view things vary, depending on whether you are using C++ or Java for example, which might make this simple example a lot more confusing...

Comment: The point of all of this is that the user of the class do not have to worry about that.

Comment: @tehlexx and Trollkemada: while I understand where you're coming from, I have to respectfully disagree.  It is indeed very important for a user to understand how the language is implemented, even if a garbage collector is around to help you out.  One of the most common problems I find when I'm fixing bugs is that people don't understand the basic idea of a pointer.

Comment: @Trollkemada: You'll be better off doing the exact opposite: *not* encoding the game rules in the pieces, but in an external entity that controls the board.

Answer (score 2):

I think your idea of objects is getting confused with how objects are used.  In object oriented languages, we have pointers that indicate the memory location of an object instance:

```
Piece pointerToPieceObject = new Peon();
```

In the statement above, `pointerToPieceObject` is of "type" `Piece`.  Because `Peon` and `Queen` both inherit from `Piece`, this pointer can point to object instances of any of these types:

```
pointerToPieceObject = new Queen();
```

This is a very general concept supported in any object oriented language.  The only difference between these languages is how typing is handled (Python vs. Java for example).  The concept is called polymorphism and can be used to do much fancier things than the example above: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming

Comment: The key point is doing that from a method called on pointerToPieceObject. (So that the user is no aware of it)

Answer (score 0):

I see two easy alternatives:

1. Let `type` be a *field* of `Pice` that's set to an instance (possibly a singleton, for example implemented as an enum) of `Bishop`/`Queen`/... This way you can easily change it.
2. Simply remove the `Peon` and create a new `Queen`/`Horse`/... in its place. I don't think object identity is terribly important here.

Comment: Having a `type` field is something we sometimes do where I work, but I'm generally against it - you lose the idea of a type hierarchy (`bishop` is no longer a sub-type of `piece`, etc).

Comment: @OpenSauce: but if they *type* of the piece is not an inherently unchangeable property of the pice, then I'd argue that `Bishop` *should not* be a sub-type of piece.

Comment: true, and it's not a principle I'd defend to the death. In this particular example I think he's better off replacing one object with another.

Comment: Having a `type` field usually ends in some methods having giant switch statements where different types have different actions. This is better achieved by subclasses.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: not if the type-specific code is actually in the classes behind `type`. In other words: don't make `type` a `int` or a `String`, but make a full-fledged class `PieceType` instead. This way you can still use all the normal polymorphism approaches to keeping sane code.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you can't change an object's class. You need to replace it with a new object of the desired class.

Answer (score 0):

For a situation where a generic, basic class "upgrades" or "evolves" to a higher, more defined class, you may want all of the more defined classes (Knight, Queen, Bishop) to have a constructor that takes the Peon class, in this case the Pawn. If the Pawn and Knight and Queen and all the pieces have a common base, then in the constructor of the Knight/Queen/etc you will have access to protected variables that are in that base class and can clone the Pawn into the next class.

```
class Pawn extends ChessPiece {...}

class Queen extends ChessPiece {
    public Queen(Pawn p) {
        // DON'T accept a ChessPiece unless you want
        // knights or rooks to become queens.

        // copy p's variables here
    }
}

ChessPiece piece= new Pawn();
// Sometime later...
if (piece is Pawn)
    piece = new Queen((Pawn)piece);
```

This is as close as you'll probably be able to get to changing the class.